# Can I copy debug.keystore from one PC to another?

Tags: android

Can I copy the debug.keystore in My home directory to another PC's home directory? Does it have to be Linux on Linux, and Windows and Windows? Can I copy Linux keystores to Windows, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

I've created a keystore for a project and share it with my team. Everyone is able to build with the same key.
I've created it in Linux and it was used in Linux and in Windows. We didn't try the other way round, but it should work.